# add or sub Calendar

Tags: java, date

can i use calender by using parameter  like if date 5-6-2018 to 26-9-2018 
i'm looking for many solve but i didn't get plz i need help for my homework

don't care about 31 or 30 days or Leap Year just i need how to do it

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
  this.day = day;
  this.month=month;
  this.year=year;
}




public void setDay(int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public void setmonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
  }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;  
    }

 public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
```

Comment: You can do whatever you like

Comment: Sorry, your question is not very clear.  Are you asking how to break a String like `26-9-2018` into a day, month and year, without using the built-in Java `DateTimeFormatter` or related classes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally i solved T_T very easy i take 2 weeks for solving

```
 public Date1(int d, int m, int y) {

        this.day = d;
        this.month = m;
        this.year = y;
    }



  public void addDay() {
    month--;
    Calendar m = Calendar.getInstance();
    m.set(year, month, day);
    m.add(day, 5);

    java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(m.getTimeInMillis());
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(" date is  " + df.format(d));

}
```